# Building C++ Project in Netbeans and Getting Lots of Undefined Reference Errors (need to link GDI?)

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I'm trying to compile an old AI project I found [here](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html). I am using Netbeans 7.1 I've installed cygwin and the appropriate packages, as I can compile all the Netbeans sample projects. I've put all the files into a project named "sweepers" and when I try to build it, I get this output:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/sweepers.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
g++.exe     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/sweepers build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CMinesweeper.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/utils.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/C2DMatrix.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CNeuralNet.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/main.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CTimer.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CGenAlg.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CParams.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o -L/cygdrive/C/cygwin/lib -L/cygdrive/C/cygwin/lib/w32api 
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/main.o: In function `_Z10WindowProcP6HWND__jjl':
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:76: undefined reference to `_CreateCompatibleDC@4'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:80: undefined reference to `_CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:85: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:136: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:140: undefined reference to `_CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:145: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:157: undefined reference to `_BitBlt@36'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:171: undefined reference to `_BitBlt@36'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:180: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:183: undefined reference to `_DeleteDC@4'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/main.cpp:184: undefined reference to `_DeleteObject@4'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o: In function `_ZN11CControllerC2EP6HWND__':
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:82: undefined reference to `_CreatePen@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_CreatePen@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:84: undefined reference to `_CreatePen@12'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o: In function `_ZN11CControllerC1EP6HWND__':
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:82: undefined reference to `_CreatePen@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_CreatePen@12'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o:/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:84: more undefined references to `_CreatePen@12' follow
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o: In function `_ZN11CControllerD2Ev':
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:112: undefined reference to `_DeleteObject@4'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:113: undefined reference to `_DeleteObject@4'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:114: undefined reference to `_DeleteObject@4'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:115: undefined reference to `_DeleteObject@4'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o: In function `_ZN11CControllerD1Ev':
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:112: undefined reference to `_DeleteObject@4'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o:/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:113: more undefined references to `_DeleteObject@4' follow
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o: In function `_ZN11CController6RenderEP5HDC__':
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:225: undefined reference to `_TextOutA@20'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:231: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:242: undefined reference to `_MoveToEx@16'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:246: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:249: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:254: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:261: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:271: undefined reference to `_MoveToEx@16'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:275: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:278: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:281: undefined reference to `_MoveToEx@16'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:285: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:288: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:290: undefined reference to `_MoveToEx@16'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:291: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:293: undefined reference to `_MoveToEx@16'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:297: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:303: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/1369961084/CController.o: In function `_ZN11CController9PlotStatsEP5HDC__':
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:321: undefined reference to `_TextOutA@20'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:324: undefined reference to `_TextOutA@20'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:333: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:335: undefined reference to `_MoveToEx@16'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:339: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:347: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:349: undefined reference to `_MoveToEx@16'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:353: undefined reference to `_LineTo@12'
/cygdrive/f/Users/Jonathon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sweepers/../../../Desktop/sweepers/CController.cpp:359: undefined reference to `_SelectObject@8'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/sweepers.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I've been googling these errors and come to the conclusion I am missing one or more libraries that have been included (this is just a guess though, as this is my first time compiling c++ or any kind of C outside of xCode on Mac.)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I feel like its extremely simple but I'm just missing a critical piece of information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely missing some GDI libraries at linking time. Someone knowledgeable at cygwin will probably let you know how to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I found some post on a forum from a long time ago where someone recommended including gdi32 or something like that but I have no idea how to get these things...

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't really know what that means... right click the project, go to linker, then what?

Comment: ah, well I went into the cygwin/lib/w32api/ and found libgdi32.a, so I went to linker in project properties and put it there. That fixed the errors. Thanks guys.